# Executing 'killall Finder' in Terminal raises reopening windows popup

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I open Terminal, type killall Finder, press enter to execute, then Finder icon bounces and the well known error popup appears:

```
The last time you opened Finder, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. 
Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?
If you choose not to reopen windows, you may have to open and position the      
windows yourself.

Don't Reopen | Reopen
```

I have absolutely no idea why!

[image: Screenshot showing Finder crash log and popup]

How can I find out what process is causing this? The only thing that had changed on my system before this started happening was that I had booted into safe mode. This makes me think its a third party app thats the root cause. As I remember a similar issue happening with Google Chrome last year, I uninstalled that. No difference. The popup still happens any time I execute killall on Finder. What window/s is it talking about? Where can I find that information? Thanks!

Comment: In the example in the screenshot the thread that is crashing is number 12, could you show us the trace for thread 12? That might help diagnose the fault. Or could you paste an entire crash log to http://pastebin.com.

Comment: HI Alistair- thanks for getting back to me. How can I get the trace for thread 12 or any thread? Sorry- not familiar with system level debugging/monitoring like this. BTW, looks like that file was deleted by system? I have quite a number of them if useful. The thread number changes often, but more than likely, its a reference to HIToolbox. As its likely a third party app cause (I guess), I essentially one by one turned off the background apps then ran the bash command. For some reason, it appears to be Box thats responsible; would be great to know how to trace it more exactly, just in case..

Comment: In the screenshot you posted above you can see the backtraces for threads 0 to 6 and part of 7. I was just meaning for you to show us what it listed lower down in the same file for thread 12. If Box is the cause of the crashes and you still have some of the crash reports, my guess is that you'll see Box mentioned in the backtrace for the crashing threads (the number of the crashing thread will likely be different each time). Other useful information in the crash logs is the list of "Binary Images" to see which things are being loaded into the process.